# Subtracting time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have 2 NSDate object thats shows 24hour time. Is there a way I can subtract those two times and put the result in a label. Ive searched for a method but couldn't find one. The only thing I could find was cover it to a double with timeIntervalFromDate method, which returns a double and I need the 24hour representation of that.

Answer (score 1):

It just returns an `NSTimeInterval` that is typedef `double` NSTimeInterval is a representation in seconds.
Doing the math to know how may hours are in x seconds, you just need to divide the retuned interval to 3600 seconds and round the result.

I've build a simple extension to be used in swift to help in calendrical calculation, you can find it here: [AFSwiftDateExtension](https://github.com/DrAma999/AFSwiftDateExtension)

Comment: I did try this and it works fine, I just have a small bug, where if its a straight hour difference its calculating 59 minutes instead

Comment: Probably this is beach it also takes into account milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

This function may solve your problem:

```
func hoursFrom(earlierDate : NSDate, laterDate:NSDate) -> Int
{
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: earlierDate, toDate: laterDate, options: nil).hour
}
```

Adapted from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182023/getting-the-difference-between-two-nsdates-in-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds).

Answer (score 0):

```
extension NSTimeInterval {
    var time:String {
        return String(format:"%02d:%02d:%02d", Int((self/3600.0)%24), Int((self/60.0)%60), Int((self)%60))
    }
}

println(30.time)    // "00:00:30"
println(60.time)    // "00:01:00"
println(600.time)   // "00:10:00"
println(3600.time)  // "01:00:00"
```

Comment: That's neat. Would add some handling for negative values.

Comment: @Eiko you can use abs(-30.0).time    // "00:00:30"