# To change the background color of the cells with the earlier date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, uitableview

Each cell contains the date and information(text). By default, sorting is in reverse order. It is sorted in the reverse order of the time. I want to change the background color of the cells in the cell prior to the current date.

tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexpath) as! tableViewCell
  cell.dateLabel.text = stores.date
  cell.contentLabel.text = stores.content

  let today = NSDate()
  if today == (stores.date) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
  } else {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  }

  return cell
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If you have problem with date equality comparison, try `isEqualToDate` method

Comment: What you need  is NSCalendar method isDateInToday https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/isDateInToday:

Comment: You might be interested in this one also http://stackoverflow.com/a/34457607/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date comparison is wrong. Use NSCalendar to compare NSDate by day. Good NSDate extension described here [Getting the difference between two NSDates in (months/days/hours/minutes/seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182023/getting-the-difference-between-two-nsdates-in-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds)

```
extension NSDate {
    // ...
    func daysFrom(date:NSDate) -> Int{
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Day, fromDate: date, toDate: self, options: []).day
    }
    //...
}
```

Using this extension in you code:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexpath) as! tableViewCell
  cell.dateLabel.text = stores.date
  cell.contentLabel.text = stores.content

  if (stores.date.daysFrom(NSDate()) == 0) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
  } else {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  }

  return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

`let today = NSDate()` will be (practically) different everytime you call it, as it gets the NSDate for the exact moment in time it was called, down to sub-milliseconds. Also, use the NSDate method `isEqualToDate:` for date comparison, as `==` will simply compare object references. So your problem is that `if today == (stores.date)` will always fail for two reasons.

Try having dates that are less accurate, perhaps down to the day, for this comparison. You could use `NSDateComponents` to remove the time from the NSDate.