# How to get the number of days since NSDate's Reference Date?

Tags: swift, nsdate

I saw in the [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate) about NSDate that Date objects represents an invariant time interval relative to an absolute reference date. How can I get the number of days since that Reference Date?

Edit: I saw solutions for a similar question, but I'm searching for a solution that don't force me to enter specific dates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 - find number of calendar days between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075850/swift-3-find-number-of-calendar-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use calendar method dateComponents from Date to Date and pass only the day component:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)     //  "2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000" 
let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date, to: Date()).day    // 5971
```

Comment: Thank you Leo! I was looking for something like that, that is, not to use any date.