# How to change the hours and minutes in an existing Date object in Swift?

Tags: swift

I need to compare two `Date` object to get the day difference between them, for example: 10/10 compares with today 10/7 will be `3`, but the `Date` object returned to me from server is not aligned with the current time. There will be a few minutes difference which results in 10/10 being `2` days ahead of 10/7 because of the delay

I found a line of code that can give me a `Date` object of the current time, but I want to convert an **existing `Date` object** from somewhere else, how do I do it?

```
let today = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!
```

e.g. `2020-10-08 16:08:57.259580+0000` I want it to be `2020-10-08 00:00:00 +0000` something like this

Comment: You could work with `DateComponents`

Comment: @AndreasOetjen this is not true

Comment: Don’t use midnight. Just parse your date string first. Then set it to 12pm. For calendrical calculations you should always use noon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 3 - find number of calendar days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075850/swift-3-find-number-of-calendar-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use midnight. Just parse your date string first. For calendrical calculations you should always use noon. First create a custom date format to parse your date string properly.

```
extension Formatter {
    static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSxx"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

Then create a helper to convert your date to noon time and another one to calculate the days between two dates and set them to noon:

```
extension Date {
    var noon: Date {
        Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }
    func days(from date: Date) -> Int {
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date.noon, to: noon).day!
    }
    var daysFromToday: Int { days(from: Date()) }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let dateString = "2020-10-08 16:08:57.259580+0000"
let now = Date()  // "Oct 8, 2020 at 5:56 AM"
print(Formatter.iso8601.string(from: now))  // "2020-10-08 08:56:46.179000+0000\n"
if let date = Formatter.iso8601.date(from: dateString) {  // "Oct 8, 2020 at 1:08 PM"
    let days = Date().days(from: date)  // 0
}
```

---

```
let dateString = "2020-10-10 16:08:57.259580+0000"
if let date = Formatter.iso8601.date(from: dateString) {
    let days = date.daysFromToday  // 2
}
```