# Firebase and timer's, Changing permissions based on time passed

Tags: firebase, swift2, xcode7, nstimer, firebase-authentication

I have created a login and signup page in my iPhone app linked to firebase-Auth. I also have a view controller where people can submit text. I am wanting to know if there is a way to start a 24 hour timer when the user has first submitted so when the timer reaches 0, the user is able to submit again.

Answer (score 2):

What i am guessing is that you are using a button for submitting that text So every time your user clicks that button, send a call to your Firebase Database and check for the timestamp last posted , if that timestamp is older than 24 hours you let the user submit the *text* otherwise...

**Saving the Text First time**

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("lastPostedText").setValue(["text" : "This is the text", "timeStamp " : Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate*1000)])
```

**Retrieving your Data at every button click**

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("lastPostedText").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock : {(snapshot) in 
  if snapshot.exists(){

      if snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

          let timeSince = snapDict["timeStamp"] as! Double
          // Check the timeSince against NSDate, if it has been more than 24 hours then let him post the text else show him an alert t
            }
       }else{

         //User hasn't submitted even a single text yet
         FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("lastPostedText").setValue(["text" : "This is the text", "timeStamp " : NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate])
     }
)}
```

snapDict would look something like this:-

```
lastPostedText:{
   text : ...,
    timeStamp : 1234234556

   }
```

For finding the difference between your currentDate and timestamp see this answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27184261/6297658

and converting timeStamp to **NSDate**, just :-

```
var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timestamp)
```

For knowing the time lapsed between the timeStamp and the current date timestamp look up : [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40201899/6297658)

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer @Dravidian , Although i have some issues with it including- What is snapDict and how do i check if the user has posted 24 hours before!