# How to compare 2 dates and get how far they are apart from each other

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this string date value

```
let stringDate = 2018-06-10T13:57:23.232+0000
```

the string date format will always be the same and I want to have output similar to one of these

```
6 year, 3 month, 1 day
or
3 month, 20 days
or
1 day
```

Basically I'm comparing the stringDate with current date and display how far they are apart from each other.

I'm able to get the date from string using this

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    var dateFromString: Date?
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    if let dateReturn = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate) {
        dateFromString = dateReturn
    }
```

but I'm stuck on how to get the custom input like above. Thank you for helping me

Comment: Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294864/difference-between-2-dates-in-weeks-and-days-using-swift-3-and-xcode-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 2 dates in weeks and days using swift 3 and xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294864/difference-between-2-dates-in-weeks-and-days-using-swift-3-and-xcode-8)

Comment: Thank you very much