# Modifiy child constantly by using the UploadDate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently building an Instagram clone.
I am quit new so please forgive me if this question is answered easily.

I just want to have a specific score attached to each post.
I already managed to give each new post a score 0f 0 to start with and each time its liked it increases by 100, disliked it decreases by 100.
for every comment it grows by 50 points.
Because I want to order them smartly and want it to show different posts at the top over time I wanted to include a third variable which influences the score.

I want it to decrease the score by -10 each hour since its been uploaded.

The increase and decrease is done in my  function incrementLikes() /incrementComments() .
I know that I can't modify the value of score for the time since its uploaded there, but I don't know where else.

My date extension (prob where I can do it?)

extension Date {

```
func timeAgoDisplay() -> String {

    let secondsAgo = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince(self))

    let minute = 60
    let hour = 60 * minute
    let day = hour * 24
    let week = day * 7
    let month = week * 4

    let quotient : Int
    let unit: String

    if secondsAgo < minute {
        quotient = secondsAgo
        unit = "Sekunde"
    } else if secondsAgo < hour {
        quotient = secondsAgo / minute
        unit = "Minute"
    } else if secondsAgo < day {
        quotient = secondsAgo / hour
        unit = "Stunde"
    } else if secondsAgo < week {
        quotient = secondsAgo / day
        unit = "Tage"
    } else if secondsAgo < month {
        quotient = secondsAgo / week
        unit = "Woche"
    } else  {
        quotient = secondsAgo / month
        unit = "Monat"
    }

    return "Vor \(quotient) \(unit)\(quotient == 1 ? "" : "n")"
}

}
```

my function in homeTableViewCell where I set the date

func updateView() {

```
    captionLabel.userHandleLinkTapHandler = { label,string, range in
        let mention = String(string.characters.dropFirst())

        API.User.observeUserByUsername(username: mention.lowercased(), completion: { (user) in
            self.delegate?.goToProfileUserViewController(userId: user.id!)

        })
    }

    guard let count = post?.commentCount else {return}
    if count == 0 {
        commentButton.setTitle("Schreibe den ersten Kommentar", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }else if count == 1 {
        commentButton.setTitle("Sieh dir den ersten Kommentar an", for: UIControlState.normal)

    } else {
        commentButton.setTitle("Alle \(count) Kommentare ansehen", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    let timeAgoDisplay = post?.creationDate?.timeAgoDisplay()

    timeLabel.text = timeAgoDisplay
    }
```

thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can schedule a timer and set its hit time for an hour and perform whatever is required.

Comment: I think that won't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of updating the score every hour using a time is based on the idea that the app is constantly running, which seems flawed.
You could instead have something like

```
var score: Int {
    return likes*100 - dislikes*100 + comments*50 - hoursSinceUpload()*10
}
```

where hoursSinceUpload is computed by something like (see [Getting the difference between two NSDates in (months/days/hours/minutes/seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182023/getting-the-difference-between-two-nsdates-in-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds) for reference)

```
func hoursSinceUpload() -> Int {
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: uploadDate, to: Date()).hour
}
```

Comment: hey thanks, that seems like a good idea. how would you compute the hoursSinceUpload() ?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give it a try as soon as I have time. Actually that's what I have been looking for, to get the difference from these two dates and the easily mupltiply lt for decreasing the score

Comment: I made a solution which works fine now, all posts will be updated when their reloaded.

Comment: Glad that I could help. It would be nice, if you would accept my answer.