# Why does Date formatter returns date correctly but time is showing as 00:00:00 when converting string to NSDate

Tags: swift, swift2, nsdateformatter

I have a function where i have to retrieve a date from my own sqlite db of app. I have saved it using the formatter

My work flow

1..Save a date to db on Application did enter background(Saved as String)

2..When application become foreground again i make a date instance at that point of time too. Now i have two date's.

3..Convert both dates to correct format and get the seconds difference.

Convert from date to String-->

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.Z"
    let myString = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()) // i get value"2017-05-18 16:49:38.+0530"
```

But when i reconvert it to NSDate(I Mean when i convert this to string again)-->

```
 let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.Z"

        let lastloginDate=formatter.dateFromString(lastLogin) // i get value(Converting back to string \n for checking as the time difference was zero ) 2017-05-18 00:00:00.+0530
```

I want to compare two dates like a session out service , I do this by getting the calendar components difference of minute. However since its coming like this, the difference his always zero .

```
 let myString1 = formatter.stringFromDate(date1)
        let myString2 = formatter.stringFromDate(date2)
        print("DATE 1\(myString1) DATE 2 \(myString2)")

        let components = calendar.components(flags, fromDate: date2, toDate: date1, options: [])
        let diff = components.second
             print("Diffrence is \(diff)") // Always zero
```

Why is this?

Comment: How is the date in the first code block related to the date in the second code block? What are the dates and flags in the third code block? A [mcve] would be helpful. – Note that can use [`compare(_:to:toUnitGranularity:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1415661-compare) to compare two dates up to second granularity.

Comment: You can refer this answer.[Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27184261/7266861)

Comment: @VimaliOs Please avoid "Try this". Put the title of the question in the link. And if it's the same questions, flag this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
    let myString1 = formatter.stringFromDate(date1)
    let myString2 = formatter.stringFromDate(date2)
    print("DATE 1\(myString1) DATE 2 \(myString2)")

    let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: myString1, toDate: myString2, options: [])
    let diff = components.second
         print("Difference is \(diff)")
```