# how to subtract the date with time in swift3

Tags: ios, datetime, swift3, nstimer

I have two values like Todaytime 2017-10-30 15:31:51 and
Expiretime 2017-10-31 10:02:17 --> string format like this, Now I subtract the **Todaytime** and **Expiretime** getting the answer, I will show on UIlabel with running time i.e., Reduces the Secounds like 23:59:29, 23:59:30...like that. I can reduces the time can you please any one help me. in iOS

how to subtract the Todaytime and Expiretime in iOS swift3
  Todaytime 2017-10-30 15:31:51 
  Expiretime 2017-10-31 10:02:17

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182023/getting-the-difference-between-two-nsdates-in-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds][1]

Comment: Note that in Swift property names and method names should start with lower case letters. (Classes and types should start with upper case letters.) This is a strong convention and one you should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `timeIntervalSinceDate()`, as in Gurdev's answer. That would give you a difference between the dates in seconds.

If you want the difference in calendar units, though, you should use the `Calendar` function `dateComponents(_:from:to:)`. That would give you hours/minutes/seconds, days/hours/minutes, or whatever units you specify.

If you want to display the difference as a string, you should create a `DateComponentsFormatter`.  That class has the function `string(from:to:)` which will build a formatted string directly from your 2 dates.

Answer (score 1):

`let diff = Expiretime.timeIntervalSinceDate(Todaytime)`

This will give you the difference as NSTimeInterval

Comment: hi Gurdev I put it but it's Shows the value of type String has no member in 'timeIntervalSinceDate' My Expiredate is in string format I converted into int or dounle the app will crash with reason optional value.

Comment: If your variables are of String datatype then you need to convert them to NSDate first. Use NSDateFormatter & its method `dateFromString` to convert String data to NSDate.