# Show cell creation time in a table (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

How can I make it so that the cell shows the time it was created and edited?

I could not find anything about this

**minutes / hours / days / weeks, etc.**

**Example:**
[image]

**Code part:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.nameText?.text = myData[indexPath.row]
    //
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    let stringDate = formatter.string(from: date)
    //
    cell.NoneLabel?.text = stringDate
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm you question: You need the time passed since last edited/ created, is that right? For instance: "3 Minutes ago"; "5 days ago"?

Comment: @dvp.petrov Yes

Comment: [`doesRelativeDateFormatting `](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415848-doesrelativedateformatting)... meh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `Date()` in the `cellForRowAt` method.

This `Date()` will give you the current date time when the cell was created.

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
let stringDate = formatter.string(from: date)
```

You can change the format with whatever you want.

Then with that you can calculate how much time ago the cell was created.
To calculate that please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182023/getting-the-difference-between-two-nsdates-in-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds/27184261).

Comment: I have a new time every time I open the VC

Comment: Yes, you want that, right?
You need to add that code in the cellForRowAt method and then calculate the time ago

Comment: I do not really understand how to use it((                                  - I need to save the date of edited/ created the cell
I put this code in cellForRowAt

Comment: You need a cell and a label on it, then you can set the label.text = stringDate

Comment: so the date will constantly change when you open VC with a table

Comment: but how to make sure that the date does not change more

Comment: Oh, got it. If you want to store that date in some place, then you need a backend with a database, or you can use FireBase.
Maybe you can store them in the AppUserDefault, but I don´t recommend you this for this user case.