# Calculating the difference between two dates in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateinterval

I've seen many approaches how to compute the difference between two dates in terms of a particular date component, e.g. in days, hours, months etc. (see [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27184261/2062785)):

```
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: fromDate, to: toDate).hour
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: fromDate, to: toDate).day
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: fromDate, to: toDate).month
```

What I haven't seen is how to make calculations with the actual `Date` objects. Something like

```
func computeNewDate(from fromDate: Date, to toDate: Date) -> Date    
     let delta = toDate - fromDate
     let today = Date()
     if delta < 0 {
         return today
     } else {
         return today + delta
     }
}
```

I have seen the [`DateInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateinterval) type introduced in iOS 10 but according to the documentation

> [it] does not support reverse intervals i.e. intervals where the duration is less than 0 and the end date occurs earlier in time than the start date.

That makes it inherently difficult to calculate with dates – especially when you don't know which one is the earlier date.

**Is there any clean and neat approach to compute time differences between `Date`s directly** (and adding them to `Date` instances again) **without computing with their `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`?**

Comment: The [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1409748-compare) describes a compare function that will order the dates for you so you can run your evaluation.

Comment: What's the problem with `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`?

Comment: @Jake: Sure I can compare dates with that but I cannot compute time intervals between two dates which I can then add to another date. The function I have included in my question is only an example for I made up to show some application of it, admittedly a very simple one that could be implemented in a nicer way. But it's not the question. The question is how to compute date differences easily with an intuitive syntax.

Comment: @AndréSlotta: The problem is that it makes code less readable, less beautiful and less intuitive: `toDate - fromDate` is a lot easier to read than `toDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - fromDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`.

Comment: Plus it's not clear to me why Swift wouldn't let me subtract two dates directly.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom operator for `Date`:

```
extension Date {

    static func - (lhs: Date, rhs: Date) -> TimeInterval {
        return lhs.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - rhs.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    }

}
```

With this operator I can now compute the difference between two dates on a more abstract level without caring about `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` or what exactly the reference date is – and without losing precision, for example:

```
let delta = toDate - fromDate
```

Obviously, I didn't change much, but for me it's a lot more readable and consequent: Swift has the `+` operator already implemented for a `Date` and a `TimeInterval`:

> ```
> /// Returns a `Date` with a specified amount of time added to it.
> public static func + (lhs: Date, rhs: TimeInterval) -> Date
> ```

So it's already supporting

```
Date + TimeInterval = Date
```

Consequently, it should also support

```
Date - Date = TimeInterval
```

in my opinion and that's what I added with the simple implementation of the `-` operator. Now I can simply write the example function exactly as mentioned in my question:

```
func computeNewDate(from fromDate: Date, to toDate: Date) -> Date    
     let delta = toDate - fromDate // `Date` - `Date` = `TimeInterval`
     let today = Date()
     if delta < 0 {
         return today
     } else {
         return today + delta // `Date` + `TimeInterval` = `Date`
     }
}
```

It might very well be that this has some downsides that I'm not aware of at this moment and I'd love to hear your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 56):

You can use :

```
let delta = fromDate.distance(to: toDate)
```

Comment: This is a super helpful function. Just that, it's available only on iOS 13+

Comment: Please upvote this one! iOS13 is common at the moment, the way higher voted do overvomplicate things if your are developing iOS apps nowadays.

Answer (score 55):

You can extension with custom operator, and return tuples

```
extension Date {

    static func -(recent: Date, previous: Date) -> (month: Int?, day: Int?, hour: Int?, minute: Int?, second: Int?) {
        let day = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: previous, to: recent).day
        let month = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: previous, to: recent).month
        let hour = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: previous, to: recent).hour
        let minute = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: previous, to: recent).minute
        let second = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: previous, to: recent).second

        return (month: month, day: day, hour: hour, minute: minute, second: second)
    }

}
```

Using:

```
let interval = Date() - updatedDate
print(interval.day)
print(interval.month)
print(interval.hour)
```

Comment: It helped me a lot. **Working properly in swift 5**. Thanks bro

Answer (score 37):

Simply [`toDate.timeIntervalSince(fromDate)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779636-timeintervalsince).

To reimplement your function without adding any extension:

```
func computeNewDate(from fromDate: Date, to toDate: Date) -> Date  {  
     let delta = toDate.timeIntervalSince(fromDate) 
     let today = Date()
     if delta < 0 {
         return today
     } else {
         return today.addingTimeInterval(delta) 
     }
}
```

Comment: Remember that this function is only available in macOS 10.15 or newer.

Answer (score 13):

I found a builtin solution to calculate the difference between 2 dates.

`let delta = toDate.timeIntervalSince(fromDate)`

Comment: [This has been suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54751685/2062785) by @cakraww already.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like…

```
func computeNewDate(from fromDate: Date, to toDate: Date) -> Date {
    let delta = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: fromDate, to: toDate).second!
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: delta, to: Date())!
}
```

Comment: That's using the components again, not the inherent dates. `delta` will be an integer  representing seconds, so this function loses precision for any date that is not a multiple of a full second.