# Calculating the number of days between two dates in swift

Tags: swift, date, variables

Why does the result of using the variable today rather than Date() when calculating the number of days between two dates make a difference in swift?

```
var numDays: Int
var today = Date()
var twoWeeksFromNow: Date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, 
value: 14, to: Date())!

var numDaysWithDate: Int = 
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: 
twoWeeksFromNow).day!
var numDaysWithToday: Int = 
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: today, to: 
twoWeeksFromNow).day!

print(numDaysWithDate) // 13
print(numDaysWithToday) // 14
```

Comment: Don’t post pictures of code. Edit your question and past in the code. Then select it and tap the code tag button (`{}`) to code format it.

Comment: My b, I will change it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56239944/10512612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the order that you're creating your variables and comparing them.

The first thing you do is create `today`. Then, you create `twoWeeksFromNow`, based on a new `Date()` that will be *slightly* further in the future than `today` was. On my machine, in a playground, the second date is about 300 microseconds further in the future than the first.

Then, for `numDaysWithDate`, you compare `twoWeeksFromNow` to *another* new `Date()`, even more *slightly* in the future. So, your time frame is *very slightly* less than 2 full weeks, giving you 13 days.

But, for `numDaysWithToday`, you compare `twoWeeksFromNow` with the original `today`, which was created *before* `twoWeeksFromNow` was, making it *slightly* longer than 2 weeks, giving you 14 days.

If you change the order of the the `today` and `twoWeeksFromNow` declarations, you can see a different result:

```
var twoWeeksFromNow: Date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day,
value: 14, to: Date())!
var today = Date()
```

Now, because `today` was created slightly later than the date that `twoWeeksFromNow` was created from, both results are 13.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to understand can be boiled down to this. The following code:

```
var today = Date()
print("Woof")
print(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - today.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate )
```

Logs a value larger than 0. On my machine, it displays a value of `0.00047898292541503906`.

That's because the value of the second `Date()` is captured after `today` is captured. By adding a print statement, slows the code enough so that the two values are over 4 milliseconds apart. By removing the print statement the two Date() values are less than 2 milliseconds apart.

If you do a series of Calendar/Date calculations and take a new value of `Date()` each time, the new `Date` will be a tiny fraction of a second later than the "today" value you capture at the beginning of your code. The difference is enough to throw off your number of days calculations, as @jnpdx explained in their excellent answer. (voted)