# Any better way to change timer every 24 hours in the background - SwiftUI

Tags: date, swiftui, timer, picker, watchos

I have a complex issue and if u make it clearer to me, I think it might help many lads. I am stuck due to impossibility to run a timer in the background (when app is closed). Moreover, I didn't find anything that could directly correspond to my situation.*(The question is mentioned bellow)*

**Explanation**

My watchOS app allow to make goals.It has two pickers where the user chooses how many weeks/months/days will be settled to the deadline. `@State private var values = ["Weeks", "Months", "Years"]` - that are the values of the second picker.

```
Picker(selection: $indexnum, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(1...12, id:\.self) { indexnum in
              Text(String(indexnum))
           }
         }
      
       Picker(selection: $index, label: Text("")) {
        ForEach(0..<values.count, content: { index in
             Text(self.values[index])
          })
        }
```

After the user made a pick, I am saving everything to the Core Data. However, I give a condition to "convert" my weeks/months/years to the approximate number of days by multiplying on picker indexes:

```
private func addGoal(){
if index == 0 {
    pickedValueDateN = 7 * indexnum ///--> I will give an explanations why I need two values further
    pickedValueDateN1 = 7 * indexnum
    } else if index == 1{
        pickedValueDateN = 30 * indexnum
        pickedValueDateN1 = 30 * indexnum
    } else if index == 2{
        pickedValueDateN = 365 * indexnum
        pickedValueDateN1 = 365 * indexnum
} else {
    pickedValueDateS = "N/A"
    pickedValueDateN = 1
}
let goal = NewGoal(context: context)
goal.dateAdded = Date()
goal.pickedValueDateN = Int64(pickedValueDateN) ////ALL DAYS
goal.pickedValueDateN1 = Int64(pickedValueDateN1) ////MINUS DAYS
do{
    try context.save()
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}catch let err{
    print(err.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

After all these manipulations I have an approximate number of days till the user's deadline. That is Okay for me, because I do not need precision.

So, I passed this number of days to the other View and made a timer:

```
 let timer = Timer.publish(every: 86400, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

 Text("\(dayString(time: Int(item.pickedValueDateN1))) days left")
                    .onReceive(timer){ _ in
                        if item.pickedValueDateN1 > 0 {
                           item.pickedValueDateN1 -= 1
                    }else{
                        self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                    }    
                }

/////Function:
func dayString(time: Int) -> String {
    let days   = Int(time)
    return String(format:"%02i", days)
}
```

Moreover, I am calculating how many days has passed by subtracting `item.pickedValueDateN1` out of `item.pickedValueDateN` (because one has all the deadline days and the other declining due to the timer).

**So, to conclude and state my question:**

1. Everything works perfectly except the thing, that as soon as I leave the app - timer stops. I'd like the app to read how many days has passed since the time the goal was created and subtract that out of `item.pickedValueDateN1`. I read that I can do something using `Date()`. E.g. If user passes the app to the background, then returns and the app calculates how much has passed. it will be a nice one, however, I do not know how to implement it correctly.
2. If You have any other suggestions, let me now please!

   var dateFromNow: Date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding:  .second,
   value: pickedValueDateN, to: Date())!

   ```
   var numDaysWithToday: Int =
   Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: Date(), to:
   dateFromNow).second!
   ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the number of days between two dates in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67854982/calculating-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-swift)

Comment: @loremipsum That is not exactly what I am looking for. My question is how to subtract from `item.pickedValueDateN1` 1 day every 24 hours...even if the app is in the background.

Comment: The timer thing won’t work. Your best bet is to use use a computed property by that uses your deadline and today and get the difference. You said you were open to another approach. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @loremipsum Okay, I got that. And how could I run it "in the background"?.
I mean make some kind of checking how much time has passed since it has gone to the background and then subtract?

Comment: A computed property will give you the right answer every time. No extra subtracting the display will always be right. What do you need it in the background for?

Comment: @loremipsum Oh, I finally got that. I thought that it requires some kind of checking when the app returns to the foreground. Thank you, man!

Comment: @loremipsum , sorry for dumb question, but I have implemented the code you sent me. Now I would like to be sure that countdown works right. I changed everything to `.second` but the countdown hasn't started. What could be the problem? 
I added the code to my question

Comment: The countdown hasn't started? What do you mean? The date should just display. Are you looking for a timer?

Comment: @loremipsum yep. I need to display a deadline and change it every 24 hours. Some kind of a timer. The problem with my previous timer was that it couldn't work when the app goes to background. E.g. you picked 7 days deadline and the next day it should be displayed as 6 days left and the day after 5 days and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct RelativeDateView: View {
    //Goal is set for 14 days from today
    @State var goalDate: Date = Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*14-2)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //The Text with style work even with widgets
            Text(goalDate, style: .relative)
            Text(goalDate, style: .offset)
            Text("days = \(goalDate.daysUntilToday)")
            Text("weeks = \(goalDate.weeksUntilToday)")
            Text("months = \(goalDate.monthsUntilToday)")
            Text("months = \(goalDate.daysMonthsUntilToday.months)  days = \(goalDate.daysMonthsUntilToday.days)")
        }
    }
}

struct RelativeDateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RelativeDateView()
    }
}
extension Date{
    var daysUntilToday: Int{
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: Date()).day ?? 0
    }
    var weeksUntilToday: Double{
        Double(self.daysUntilToday)/Double(7)
    }
    var monthsUntilToday: Int{
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: self, to: Date()).month ?? 0
    }
    var daysMonthsUntilToday: (days: Int, months: Int){
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day,.month], from: self, to: Date())
        return (components.day ?? 0, components.month ?? 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that work if the app goes to the background?

Comment: It will show the correct date. What do you need it in the background for? It is a computed property every time it is accessed `Date()` will be refreshed

Comment: So if I a user picked 7 days,  then closes my app and comes back like in 2 days - it will be changed to the 5 days, right?

Comment: Yes, it will show the current difference. Test it out. Every time the body is loaded the number will be calculated. Close the app, etc