# Display days:hours:min:sec from Date

Tags: ios, swift, date, uilabel

I'm trying to display "days: hours: min: sec" from a `Date` in a `UILabel`. I'm using this `extension Date` from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494711/4700495) but it doesn't update the `UILabel` I have. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
extension Date {

    func offsetFrom(date : Date) -> String {

        let dayHourMinuteSecond: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        let now = Date()
        let difference = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents(dayHourMinuteSecond, from: date, to: now)

        let seconds = "\(difference.second ?? 0)s"
        let minutes = "\(difference.minute ?? 0)m" + " " + seconds
        let hours = "\(difference.hour ?? 0)h" + " " + minutes
        let days = "\(difference.day ?? 0)d" + " " + hours

        if let day = difference.day, day          > 0 { return days }
        if let hour = difference.hour, hour       > 0 { return hours }
        if let minute = difference.minute, minute > 0 { return minutes }
        if let second = difference.second, second > 0 { return seconds }
        return ""
    }

}

        // MARK: - Poll Expiration Date
        if let expirationTimeInt = post?.pollExpirationTime {
            let expirationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(expirationTimeInt))
            print(expirationDate) // prints "2018-07-11 164:19:58 PM +0000" 
            pollExpirationDate.text = expirationDate.offsetFrom(date: expirationDate) // shows nothing

        }
```

Comment: 1.: you return from `offsetFrom(date:)` as soon as one component is not zero — without ever assembling the string as you describe what should be done. 2.: you create second, minutes, hour, days, just to overwrite the variable names in the next step 3.: `expirationDate.offsetFrom(date: expirationDate)` what should be the offset by date from the same date?

Comment: **Debug** your code. Set a breakpoint in the offsetFrom function and single-step. At what point is the program flow not as you would expect it?

Comment: Are you sure that printing the date shows `"2018-07-11 164:19:58 PM +0000" ` ? With hours being 164?

Comment: Please add the real `Int` value of `expirationTimeInt` to the question.

Comment: `expirationDate` is in the future, so that all components of `difference` are negative. Therefore `offsetFrom()` returns an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much more convenient API: `DateComponentsFormatter`

```
extension Date {

    func offsetFromNow() -> String {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        return formatter.string(from: Date(), to: self)!
    }
}

let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(100000)

print(date.offsetFromNow())
```

Comment: That is correct, but not an answer to the question *"... it doesn't update the UILabel ... what I'm doing wrong ..."*

Comment: This actually solves the problem and updates the label correctly! Now it shows `3d 6h 30 min 34s`