# Get the difference between two dates in calendar days

Tags: swift

can anyone explain how can I get difference between two dates in calendar days, not in whole 24-hour periods. There is a good solution here: [Getting the difference between two NSDates in (months/days/hours/minutes/seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182023/getting-the-difference-between-two-nsdates-in-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds?newreg=51d700a55cbb416d98f8411dfb3b7f29) -- but it doesn't work for me as, for example, it gives the difference between 23:00 today and 1:30 tomorrow as 0 days despite of calendar dates differ already by 1.

Comment: What language?  What datatypes?  The strategy used can vary wildly.

Comment: @Hobadee The question is tagged Swift. The link in this question refers to a question in Swift.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40193009/1187415 to the referenced question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the normal way to calculate the difference in days with one change - convert both of your dates to midnight.

```
let d1 = ... // your first date
let d2 = ... // your second date
let cal = Calendar.current
let days = cal.dateComponents([.day], from: cal.startOfDay(for: d1), to: cal.startOfDay(for: d2)).day!
```

This will give an answer of `1` for "yesterday at 23:00" and "today at 1:30", for example.

Comment: Thank you for such an elegant idea.

Comment: This would return 0 days if you try to calculate the difference between the first day of  a daylight savings date (which used to start at 1am here in Brazil) and the day after which starts at 12am. You should use noon for days calculation.

Comment: try `let cal = Calendar.current
let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Sao_Paulo")!
let date1 =  DateComponents(calendar: cal, timeZone: timeZone, year: 2001, month: 10, day: 14).date!
let date2 =  DateComponents(calendar: cal, timeZone: timeZone, year: 2001, month: 10, day: 15).date!
cal.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2).day!`

Comment: @LeoDabus Why not post your own answer?

Comment: I am just warning you that this doesn't work, I have already talked about the same issue with Martin R. You can keep your answer as it is you you would like to