# How to get difference (hour minutest second ) time from between two date in swift 5

Tags: swift

I am using swift 5. I need to find out the (hour, minutes, second) between two string data. I have tried bellow code..

```
      var timestamp:String = "2019-12-12 01:01:02"
       var last_timestamp:String = "2019-12-12 01:55:02"

       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
       let dateold = dateFormatter.date(from: timestamp)!
       let datenew = dateFormatter.date(from: last_timestamp)!

       let calendar1 = Calendar.current
       let components = calendar1.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second], from:  dateold, to:   datenew)
       let seconds = components.second
       print("seconds idle-->",seconds)
```

Above code return 0. Please help me find out difference time in swift 5

Comment: maybe it is because 02 seconds - 02 seconds = 0? check other properties, components.minute will return 54

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182023/getting-the-difference-between-two-nsdates-in-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds

Comment: Because you have equal seconds in `timestamp` and `last_timestamp`.
If you want to get only seconds change `calendar1.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: dateold, to: datenew)` to `calendar1.dateComponents([.second], from: dateold, to: datenew)`

Answer (score 4):

You said you want the hours, minutes and seconds between the two dates, yet you are only getting the seconds components. The two dates are exactly 54 minutes and **0 seconds** apart, so that's why you got 0.

You should only pass `.hour, .minute, .second`, and print all three components:

```
let components = calendar1.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second], from:  dateold, to:   datenew)
print(components.hour!)
print(components.minute!)
print(components.second!)
```

Or, use a `DateCompoenentFormatter` which formats the components for you:

```
let componentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
print("Idle time: \(componentsFormatter.string(from: components)!)")
```