# Swift: Why DateComponentsFormatter.localizedString(from:unitsStyle:) does not work for weekday?

Tags: ios, swift

Why `DateComponentsFormatter.localizedString(from:unitsStyle:)` does not work for `weekday`?

```
let twoDays = DateComponents(day: 2)
let threeWeeks = DateComponents(weekday: 3)

DateComponentsFormatter.localizedString(from: twoDays, unitsStyle: .full) ?? "found nil" // "2 days"
DateComponentsFormatter.localizedString(from: threeWeeks, unitsStyle: .full) ?? "found nil" // returns "found nil"
```

Comment: What exactly do you think `DateComponents(weekday: 3)` would mean?

Comment: Well, I want to have a Text displaying number of weeks between two dates, and only ```weekday``` worked for me in week calculations.

Like this:
```let numberOfWeeksBeetwenTwoDates = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekdayOrdinal], from: startDate, to: endDate).weekdayOrdinal ?? 0
let numberOfWeeks = DateComponents(weekday: numberOfWeeksBeetwenTwoDates)

Text(DateComponentsFormatter.localizedString(from: twoDays, unitsStyle: .full) ?? "found nil")```

Comment: You can get now Date, create a second date adding 3 weeks to now and use [RelativeDateTimeFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/relativedatetimeformatter).This [Getting the difference between two Dates (months/days/hours/minutes/seconds) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27184261/2303865) might help as well

Comment: So this an x-y question. If you wanted to know how to display the difference between dates in weeks, you should have asked that, rather than _assuming_ that DateComponents and DateComponentsFormatter was the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateComponents` has a property named `allowedUnits`, `weekday` is not a legal unit.

The allowed units are:

**year
month
weekOfMonth
day
hour
minute
second**

see this [ref](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/1410216-allowedunits).

Comment: Thank you, and can I use ```weekday``` in calculations, and then ```weekOfMonth``` for DateComponentsFormatter, or will it cause some incompatibility problems?