# iOS: How to calculate milliseconds between two dates

Tags: ios, swift

I am working in networking swizzling of URLSession and getting every request details. However when I am trying to calculate value of request date in milliseconds, sometimes calculation is showing much higher value. In swizzling of `startLoading` we are taking current date and inside `stopLoading` we are calculating milliseconds. Below is my logic

```
let startDate: Date?
override public func startLoading() {
    startDate = Date()
}

override public func stopLoading() {
   print(fabs(startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow) * 1000)


 }
```

Comment: `Double(endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)) * 1000` seems to be correct, what's the issue though?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599172/find-difference-in-seconds-between-nsdates-as-integer-using-swift

Comment: @Tj3n I am updated by question, please check

Comment: Off-topic but don't do `fabs` on the result, you will hide "incorrect" measurements. At least return 0.0 if negative

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your stopLoading function you should call:

`print(Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate) * 1000)`

This way you will see how much time (in ms) has passed since startDate.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to find difference between two dates using Calender

```
let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: Date1, to: Date2).second
let millisecond = diff * 1000
print(millisecond)
```

Answer (score 0):

Date() function as it says in the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) is returning UTC time. Have you checked if the startDate variable is also UTC time? You should probably calculate also the difference bettween the users time zone and the UTC time.